# C# - Cannot embed interop type - still set 'Embed Interop Types' property to false

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop, com-interop

I am getting the following Error when building a project:

```
"Cannot embed interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoXXX' found in both assembly 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\office\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\OFFICE.DLL' and 'c:\myProject\lib\OFFICE.DLL'. Consider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false."
```

I am getting 130 of this errors, each with another Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoXXX like MsoLineDashStyle or MsoSyncStatusType.

Actually most References within the Project in Visual Studio hat set the property to TRUE. So I changed them all, especially OFFICE.dll, to FALSE.
The errors still occur.

After a restart of VS the property of embed interop ist still set to FALSE.

Another project within the same map uses exactly the same OFFICE.dll (also located at c:\myProject\lib\OFFICE.DLL) and also has the flag set to FALSE. Building this project does work quite fine.

The project is a little bit older and was not build for a long time.
Except for one unknown object there were no marked erros by VS. I would expect further compile errors because of this. I dont know whether this could be related to the embed-flag problem.

Any ideas what could be wrong or how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by reallive:

The first of the both dlls from the error-message
(c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\office\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\OFFICE.DLL)
was in fact named as Windows.Microsoft.Office.Core

while the second reference
(c:\myProject\lib\OFFICE.DLL)
was named as OFFICE.DLL.

Both were existing side by side in the project. After deleting one of the two references within my project there isnt any problem any more.
Also I am able to compile and run the code with embed-flag = TRUE!

So the error message was missleading here.
Thanks for listening.

Comment: for deleting reference we just have to remove the .ddl from the bin folder, right? ps-new to c#.net